# Shrink table to screen size in bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4

[image: this]

Im trying to shrink a table to fit in the screen. I'm using this code below. I'm pretty sure this happens because im using text-nowrap in the table and to clearify I don't want to scroll the table. I just want to make it smaller so it fits like the 2 tables above the 3rd. What can I do to make this happen?

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6">
  <h5>Längsta vinstserie</h5>
  <table class="table table-sm table-dark table-striped table-hover table-borderless text-nowrap alpha-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Datum</th>
        <th>Lag</th>
        <th>Resultat</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="match in winStreak" :key="match.id" class="linkRow" @click="goToMatch(match.id)">
        <td>{{match.date}}</td>
        <td>{{match.homeTeamName}} - {{match.awayTeamName}}</td>
        <td>{{match.homeTeamScore}} - {{match.awayTeamScore}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6">
  <h5>Längsta förlustserie</h5>
  <table class="table table-sm table-dark table-striped table-hover table-borderless text-nowrap alpha-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Datum</th>
        <th>Lag</th>
        <th>Resultat</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="match in losingStreak" :key="match.id" class="linkRow" @click="goToMatch(match.id)">
        <td>{{match.date}}</td>
        <td>{{match.homeTeamName}} - {{match.awayTeamName}}</td>
        <td>{{match.homeTeamScore}} - {{match.awayTeamScore}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your data itself is what's causing the table to result in this width. I would recommend changing your font size. This can be done by creating a custom class, and then assigning it to the table with the `!important` flag. It's a quick and dirty fix, but it works.

```
<style>
    .example {
        font-size: small !important;
    }
</style>

<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6 example">
...
```

Answer (score -1):

Wrap the table in a div with class name `table-responsive`. If the table has more width than scrollbar is visible.

Comment: as I said, I don't want to do that since I don't want to scroll. I want the table to shrink in size to fit the screen.